# Fancybox JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi I have been fighting this for hours and it will still not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
                        });
                    </script>

<a class="fancybox-iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bo7evVLoRzQ" data-fancybox-type="iframe"><img src="img/videoplacement.jpg" width="400px" height="315px" class="aligncenter"></a>
```

This does not work.  It just keeps opening the video in Youtube and fullscreen.
thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

add `the fancybox` class to the `<a>`

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox-iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bo7evVLoRzQ" data-fancybox-type="iframe"><img src="img/videoplacement.jpg" width="400px" height="315px" class="aligncenter"></a>
```

or change in jquery

```
$(".fancybox-iframe").fancybox();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not refering to the right `fancybox-iframe` class:

Change this line:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

to:

```
$(".fancybox-iframe").fancybox();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6x5qydL/)

P.S.

You might want to add

```
?autoplay=true  (http://www.youtube.com/embed/bo7evVLoRzQ?autoplay=true)
```

to your youtube url, then your video will start directly

Comment: I changed it to what it was and that was fancybox class then changed that in the javascript<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bo7evVLoRzQ" data-fancybox-type="iframe"><img src="img/videoplacement.jpg" width="400px" height="315px" class="aligncenter"></a>     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
       });
      </script>

Comment: What do you want to tell me with that?